# Define BoundaryMeshRegion from matrix of data

Tags: regions, mesh

Say I have a matrix 'm' with 2 columns and 'r' rows. I want to define a mesh region using each row in the matrix as a point coordinate. Something like the R=BoundaryMeshRegion[{m},Line[1,2,3....,r]] . How can I accomplish this? The 2 issues are how to transform 'm' into the list of lists (point coordinates) and secondly, how to abbreviate Line[1,2,...,r] so that I don't have to list the full sequence.

Comment: try `R = BoundaryMeshRegion[m, Line[Range[r]]]`?

Comment: Or maybe `BoundaryMeshRegion[Append[m, First[m]], Line[Mod[Range[r+1], r, 1]]]` if your point list isn't closed.